# Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate error while changing password Cognito AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am building an application. In that `Sign up`,  `Signin` and other operations are working fine. But, when I try to change password using following code, it says

```
"Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate"
```

Code is:

```
changePassword(mail: any) {
    var that = this;
    var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(this.poolData);
    var userData: any = {
        Username: mail,
        Pool: userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    // To get the session
    cognitoUser.getSession(function (err, session) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err);
            return;
        }
        var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(that.poolData);
        var userData: any = {
            Username: mail,
            Pool: userPool
        };
        var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
        var oldp = prompt('Please input old password ', '');
        var newp = prompt('Please input new password ', '');
        cognitoUser.changePassword(oldp, newp, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
                return;
            }
            alert("Password successfully changed...");
        });
    });
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong in this. Please help me solve this.

Thank you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After so much of struggle, I figured out that I was creating new Cognito user every time using

```
poolData = {
    UserPoolId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    ClientId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};
userPool: CognitoUserPool = new CognitoUserPool(this.poolData);
```

So, whenever I call this, a new cognito-user is created. So, change-password on this was not working.

When I created a common function to access `cognitoUser` and using the same everywhere worked for me.

Thank you...

Comment: Do you have code to share how you implemented this?

Comment: @MingJin, you can follow this https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Comment: @Sai, OK, that link contains an example `cognitoUser.changePassword('oldPassword', 'newPassword', callback)`. That is exactly what I'm doing on `cognitoUser` (and experiencing the mentioned error). But I don't know how to get the authenticated user (mentioned in the example description). That is why the full example from you would be so helpful.