# How to properly store a CognitoUser?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm working on a simple React/Typescript application to test Cognito and I'm running into some problems handling the user, I have a function that gets the user like so:

```
/* CognitoUtils.tsx */
import UserPool from './UserPool';
export const getCognitoUser = (phone: string): CognitoUser => {
   const userData: ICognitoUserData = {
        Username: phone,
        Pool: UserPool,
    };
    return new CognitoUser(userData);    
}
```

I have the UserPool defined in a separate file like so:

```
/* UsePool.tsx */
import { ICognitoUserPoolData, CognitoUserPool } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

const poolData: ICognitoUserPoolData = {
    UserPoolId: 'XXX',
    ClientId: 'XXX',
    Storage: window.sessionStorage 
};

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
export default userPool;
```

And this is the code I use to sign in:

```
/* CognitoUtils.tsx */
export const signIn = (phone: string) => {
    var authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
            Username: phone,
            Password: 'XXXX',
    });
    const user = getCognitoUser(phone);

    user.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function(session: CognitoUserSession) {
            console.log("Succesfully signed in", session, "current user", user);
        },
        onFailure: function(error) {
            console.log("Error while signing in", error);
        },
    });
}
```

This is working fine, the user and session objects are printed without a problem.
I have a button for signing out that calls this function:

```
/* CognitoUtils.tsx */
export const signOut = (phone: string) => {
    var user = getCognitoUser(phone);

    user.getSession((err: any, session: CognitoUserSession) => {
        console.log("Getting session error", err, "session:", session);
        user.globalSignOut({
        onSuccess: (msg: string) => {
            console.log("Succesfully signed out", msg);
            },
            onFailure: (err: globalThis.Error) => {
                console.log("Error while signing out", err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This causes the following error on `user.getSession()`:

```
Getting session error Error: Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate
```

Despite having an id token in my local storage (which is generated on sign in), I have tried saving the user in a shared variable in the same file, saving it on a redux store and even converting the object into a json and saving using localStorage, the closes I've ever got to have this working is the signOut function working after signIn but the user breaking if I refresh the page in between.

My question is, what is the proper way of storing/retrieving this user?

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656963/local-storage-is-missing-an-id-token-please-authenticate-error-while-changing-p) the closest I've found to my error but even after moving the UsePool to a separate file this still happens.

[This is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) the tutorial I've been following.

Any help is greatly appreciated.